# Create a text-based live tile image programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, imaging

I have a database-bound app that I want to display random snippets of data on a live tile. For the sake of argument, let's say quotations that I want to update daily, so the tile is a random quote-of-the-day.

I have a method that essentially creates the live tile background image by building XAML programmatically, (TextBlock in a Border in a Grid) where I can resize the text to fit, using the `Render()` method of `WriteableBitmap`. This works fine.

I've also created a `BackgroundAgent` using [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/780843/Updating-App-Tile-using-Background-Agent-in-Window) that also works fine.

The problem is when the `BackgroundAgent` fires, and I need to create a new image for the tile, I get a cross-thread access error when trying to create the XAML elements, I presume because the thread is not running on a UI thread. So I need to create my tile background image with text, but I'm not sure where to begin and my Google-Fu is coming up blank. I recall I did this years ago in WinForms, but I suspect Windows Phone is a bit different. Can someone point me in a direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to use `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. In Windows Phone you can manipulate UI and UI elements only in primary thread and that's basically what `Dispatcher` does.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190259%28v=vs.95%29.aspx